# Need to add comma to a variable for an XSL Template

Tags: xml

I'm trying to add a comma to the bill that is printed from our customer information system. From what I understand the application pulls a customer's data from sql server and creates an xml file.  Then that xml file is compared against an xsl file for formatting and a new xml file and pdf are created.

I don't know much about xml but from what I can tell the @previousread, @current, and @usage are variables that are interpreted from an xml stream from our application.  These three variables represent the previous meter read, current meter read, and consumption (usage).

My organization wants me to add commas for thousands.  As of this post our bill just posts a bunch of number together.  I don't see a problem with the way the numbers look and don't see why we need commas, but I'm expected to make it have commas.

I'm not a web developer but I do have a little experience with sql server.  I've spent about 8 hours working on this and thought I had it figured out only to see the pdf doesn't have commas.

I've seen examples online for how to format a number when its a constant value but the value for each meter read is different and I don't know how to compensate for that.

I've posted the code as it was originally and as I've edited it.

This is the original code.

```
<fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="10pt">
<fo:block border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<xsl:value-of select="@utility"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<xsl:if test="count(meter/meterread) &gt; 0">
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::meter/meterread[1]/@previousread"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-   color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::meter/meterread[last()]/@current"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>   
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-  color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(meter/meterread/@billingusage) &gt; 0">
<xsl:value-of select="sum(meter/meterread/@billingusage)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(meter/meterread/@usage)"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Here is the code as I've edited it.

```
<fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="10pt">
<fo:block border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<xsl:value-of select="@utility"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<xsl:if test="count(meter/meterread) &gt; 0">
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::meter/meterread[1]/@previousread"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::meter/meterread[last()]/@current"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>   
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(meter/meterread/@billingusage) &gt; 0">
<xsl:value-of select="sum(meter/meterread/@billingusage)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(meter/meterread/@usage)"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: What's your question? This is not a complete [mcve] as required so StackOverflow.

Comment: This is actual production code, and I didn't write it.  I'm fearful of releasing more information about our software than is necessary to solve the problem.  I accidentally pasted the exact same code twice instead of posting my edits; based on what I learned online.  According to the scant documentation provided by our software vendor, the edits I made below should work.  I'm obviously doing something wrong. I don't know if Stack Overflow allows uploading images, but it it does I can include the relevant portions of their "instruction" guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can format numbers with comma as a thousands separator using the `format-number()` function: just look it up in any reference. I've no idea where you would want to use it, perhaps around the calls on `sum()`.

By the way, there's some odd code in your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(meter/meterread/@billingusage) &gt; 0">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(meter/meterread/@billingusage)"/>
</xsl:when>
```

If `meter/meterread/@billingusage` is a set containing multiple values then it doesn't make sense to apply `string-length()` to it; if it's a single value then it doesn't make sense to apply `sum()` to it.

The expressions `@previousread`, `@current`, and `@usage` don't refer to variables, they refer to attributes in the source document.

8 hours is long enough to do quite a lot of reading, so I'm surprised you didn't find the `format-number()` function.

Comment: I don't know what to say about the odd code.  It is this way in the stylesheet we use to create bills we send out to about 29k customers each month.  I mean it works and I certainly didn't write it; I wouldn't know how.

Comment: I did find it I just accidentally posted the same original code twice.

Comment: Code that works by accident is not uncommon; but when you're inspecting code it always raises a red flag.

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong with the supplied code by visual inspection, so you're going to have to supply something that we can actually run. Note this doesn't have to be (and shouldn't be) your production code, it should be a cut-down example that's sufficient to demonstrate the problem. Given your inexperience with the tools you're using, it wouldn't surprise me if it turns out that your'e not actually running the code you think you are running. But that's wild conjecture of course - just making sure we don't rule out any possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally posted the original code twice.  Here is the code as I edited it:

```
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="10pt">
<fo:block border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<xsl:value-of select="@utility"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<xsl:if test="count(meter/meterread) &gt; 0">
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(descendant::meter/meterread[1]/@previousread, '#,###,###')"/>
</fo:block>
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(descendant::meter/meterread[last()]/@current, '#,###,###')"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>   
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-right-style="solid" border-color="black" border-width="0.2pt">
<fo:block>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(meter/meterread/@billingusage) &gt; 0">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(meter/meterread/@billingusage), '#,###,###')"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(meter/meterread/@usage), '#,###,###')"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```